# USB and Serial MIDI

Tags: arduino, usb, midi

I have a project I'm working on for sending MIDI over USB or over a standard MIDI port using an Arduino Leonardo/Nano (ATmega32u4) and I can't seem to get anything to come over either port.

I've listed my code below. USB serial works fine and I have sent data over it before. MIDI port is connected to TX/PD3/21 and goes through a 10ohm resistor before it connects to the MIDI connector.

I've tried example code to no avail and I'm not sure if my MIDI snooper is even working and I can't go into the studio to test with my normal setup.

Any help would be appreciated.

*PS. If you know of a way to transmit on both at the same time or toggle between the two ports, I'm all ears.*

````
#define ENCODER_OPTIMIZE_INTERRUPTS

#include <math.h>
#include <Encoder.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
#include <MIDI.h>
#include <USB-MIDI.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <EEPROM.h>

// ========= Variables and Constants ========= //

// Faders
#define NUM_FADERS  8
const int faderSignal[NUM_FADERS] = {A0, A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6, A7};
int faderCCs[NUM_FADERS] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
int faderChannels[NUM_FADERS] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
int faderValues[NUM_FADERS] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

// LCD
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27,16,2); 
long lastDisplayUpdateTime = 0;
bool updateFlag = true;

#define DISPLAY_HOME 0 
#define DISPLAY_EDITOR 1
int displayMode = 0;

#define SELECT_FADER    0
#define SELECT_BACK     3
#define SELECT_CC       1
#define SELECT_CHANNEL  2

bool currentlyEditingValue = false;
int editingFader = 0;
int selection = 0;

// Encoder smoothing and velocity control
#define ENCODER_A   7
#define ENCODER_B   8
#define ENCODER_SW  9

#define ENCODER_PRESS_LIMIT 500
long lastEncoderPress = 0;

Encoder enc(ENCODER_A, ENCODER_B);
long encoderElapsedTime = 0;
long lastEncoderTime = 0;


int lastEncVal = 0;
int currEncVal = 0;
int delta = 0;

int val = 0;
int lastVal = 0;

int encoderCount = 0;

// EEPROM

#define MEMORY_MAX_WRITES 100000
#define MEMORY_REGISTER_SIZE 19
#define MEMORY_CC_START 3
#define MEMORY_CH_START 11

long memoryWrites = 0;
int memoryIndex = -1 * MEMORY_REGISTER_SIZE;

// MIDI / USB
#define FADER_MARGIN 4
#define FADER_MIN_VALUE 24
#define FADER_MAX_VALUE 1000

bool forceSendMIDI = false;
int newFaderValue = 0;

#define SOURCE_SW 5

bool usingUSB = true;
bool shouldUseUSB = false;

// Load non-USB midi
MIDI_CREATE_DEFAULT_INSTANCE();

// ========= Functions ========= //

void writeMemory () {

  // Incrememnt memoryWrites long term storage
  memoryWrites++;

  // If next write will be 100,001st write to this register
  if (memoryWrites > MEMORY_MAX_WRITES) {
    // Increment to next register and clear the memoryWrites value
    memoryIndex += MEMORY_REGISTER_SIZE;
    memoryWrites = 1;
  }

  // Break up long memoryWrites into bytes and write to first 3 bytes of memory register
  EEPROM.write(memoryIndex, (memoryWrites & 0xFF0000) >> 16);
  EEPROM.write(memoryIndex + 1, (memoryWrites & 0x00FF00) >> 8);
  EEPROM.write(memoryIndex + 2, (memoryWrites & 0x0000FF));
  
  // Write CC and channel values to memory register at appropriate locations 
  for (int i=0; i<NUM_FADERS; i++) {
    EEPROM.write(memoryIndex + i + MEMORY_CC_START, faderCCs[i]);
    EEPROM.write(memoryIndex + i + MEMORY_CH_START, faderChannels[i]);
  }
}

void readMemory () {
  // Figure out where to be reading from 
  do {
     // Go to next register index (Initially one register behind zero)
    memoryIndex += MEMORY_REGISTER_SIZE;

    // Grab 3-bytes of long (4th byte not needed) memoryWrites
    memoryWrites = 0;
    memoryWrites |= EEPROM.read(memoryIndex) << 16;
    memoryWrites |= EEPROM.read(memoryIndex + 1) << 8;
    memoryWrites |= EEPROM.read(memoryIndex + 2);

    // If fresh EEPROM shows negative value
    if (memoryWrites < 0) {
      // Set to 0
      memoryWrites = 0;
      // Break up long memoryWrites into bytes and write to first 3 bytes of memory register
      EEPROM.write(memoryIndex, (memoryWrites & 0xFF0000) >> 16);
      EEPROM.write(memoryIndex + 1, (memoryWrites & 0x00FF00) >> 8);
      EEPROM.write(memoryIndex + 2, (memoryWrites & 0x0000FF));
    }

  // Check next index if current register exceeds maximum stable writes value
  } while (memoryWrites >= MEMORY_MAX_WRITES);  
  
  // Load in CC and channel values from the current register
  for (int i=0; i<NUM_FADERS; i++) {
    faderCCs[i]       = EEPROM.read(memoryIndex + i + MEMORY_CC_START ) % 128;
    faderChannels[i]  = EEPROM.read(memoryIndex + i + MEMORY_CH_START) % 16;
  }
}



void checkRotaryEncoder () {
  // If encoder is currently being pressed, handle it
  if (!digitalRead(ENCODER_SW)) { encoderPressed(); }

  // Get current encoder value
  val = enc.read();

  // If value has changed since last check
  if (val != lastVal) {

    // Incrememnt counter to account for quadrature encoding
    //encoderCount = (encoderCount + 1) % 4;

    //if (!(digitalRead(ENCODER_A) || digitalRead(ENCODER_B)) ) {

      // If counter at arbitrary point in 4 occurances or once per "click"
      //if (encoderCount == 0) {
  
        // If valid value from quadrature encoder
        //if (val % 4 == 0) {
  
          // If val increased due to counterclockwise motion
          if (val - lastVal > 0) {
            // Handle counterclockwise motion
            encoderMoved(1);
          } else {
            // Handle clockwise motion
            encoderMoved(-1);
          }
        }
        // Update lastVal 
        lastVal = val;
      //}
    //}
  //}
}

void encoderMoved(int delta) {

  // Get time since last encoder motion occured and update timer
  encoderElapsedTime = abs(millis() - lastEncoderTime);
  lastEncoderTime = millis();

  if (encoderElapsedTime > 100) {

  // If currently displaying editor
  if (displayMode == DISPLAY_EDITOR) {

    // If not editing a value
    if (!currentlyEditingValue) {

      // Incrememnt the selection to allow motion through the four options
      selection = (selection + delta + 4) % 4;

    // If editing a value 
    } else {

     
        
      // If encoder was turned within 25ms (super fast), increment 10x faster
      //if (encoderElapsedTime < 150) {  delta *= 10;
      // If encoder was turned within 50ms (somewhat fast), incrememnt 5x faster
      //} else 
      if (encoderElapsedTime < 200) { delta *= 5; }
      // Otherwise stick to 1x speed

      // Increment selected value and while remaining bounded
      if (selection == SELECT_FADER) {
        editingFader = (editingFader + delta + NUM_FADERS) % NUM_FADERS;
      } else if (selection == SELECT_CC) {
        faderCCs[editingFader] = (faderCCs[editingFader] + delta + 128) % 128;
      } else if (selection == SELECT_CHANNEL) {
        faderChannels[editingFader] = (faderChannels[editingFader] + delta + 16) % 16;
      }
    }

    // Force a display update
    updateFlag = true;
  }
}
}

void encoderPressed () {
    // If enough time has passed since last press (debouncing)
    if (millis() - lastEncoderPress > ENCODER_PRESS_LIMIT) {

      // If currently at home display
      if (displayMode == DISPLAY_HOME) {

        // Switch to fader editor display
        displayMode = DISPLAY_EDITOR;
        selection = SELECT_FADER;

      // If currently at editor display 
      } else if (displayMode == DISPLAY_EDITOR) {

          // If back option selected
          if (selection == SELECT_BACK) {

            // Update values in long term memory
            writeMemory();

            // Clear screen and return to home display
            lcd.clear();
            displayMode = DISPLAY_HOME;

          } else {

            // Toggle if currently editing selected value
            currentlyEditingValue = !currentlyEditingValue;
          }
      }

      // Reset debouncing timer
      lastEncoderPress = millis();

      // Force a display update
      updateFlag = true;
    }
}



void checkDisplay() {
  // If enough time has passed (helps reduce latency) and something has changed on screen
  if (millis() - lastDisplayUpdateTime > 100 && updateFlag) {

    // Handle display based on current displayMode
    if (displayMode == DISPLAY_HOME) {
      renderHome();
    } else if (displayMode == DISPLAY_EDITOR) {
      renderEditor();
    }

    // Screen is updated, turn off updateFlag
    updateFlag = false;

    // Reset update timer
    lastDisplayUpdateTime = millis();
  }
}

void renderHome () {
  // Get rid of any blinking cursors
  lcd.noBlink();
  
  // For each fader
  for (int i=0; i<NUM_FADERS; i++) {

    // Move to the approriate location on screen 
    lcd.setCursor(((i/2+1)*4)-3,i%2);

    // Print CC values, right justified to grid
    if (faderCCs[i]<100)  { lcd.print(" "); }
    if (faderCCs[i]<10)   { lcd.print(" "); }
    lcd.print(faderCCs[i]);
  }
}

void renderEditor() {
  // Render template
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print(">Fader 0  >CH   ");
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print(">CC       >EXIT ");

  // Render fader value
  lcd.setCursor(7,0);
  if (editingFader + 1 < 10) {
    lcd.print("0");
  }
  lcd.print((editingFader + 1));

  // Render CC value
  lcd.setCursor(6,1);
  if (faderCCs[editingFader] < 10) {
    lcd.print("00");
  } else if (faderCCs[editingFader] < 100) {
    lcd.print("0");
  }
  lcd.print(faderCCs[editingFader]);

  // Render channel value
  lcd.setCursor(14,0);
  if (faderChannels[editingFader] + 1 < 10) {
    lcd.print("0");
  }
  lcd.print(faderChannels[editingFader] + 1);

  // Redner the flashing selection cursor
  if (!currentlyEditingValue) {
    lcd.setCursor((selection / 2) * 10, selection % 2);
  } else {
    if (selection == SELECT_FADER) {
      lcd.setCursor(8,0);
    } else if (selection == SELECT_CC) {
      lcd.setCursor(8,1);
    } else {
      lcd.setCursor(15,0);
    }
  }
  lcd.blink();
}




void checkFaders () {
  // For each fader
  for (int i=0; i<NUM_FADERS; i++) {

    // Read the current 10 bit value
    newFaderValue = analogRead(faderSignal[i]);

    // Bound the fader to an 8 bit number with buffer room at the top and bottom
    if (newFaderValue < FADER_MIN_VALUE) {
      newFaderValue = 0;
    } else if (newFaderValue > FADER_MAX_VALUE) {
      newFaderValue = 255;
    } else {
      newFaderValue = map(newFaderValue, FADER_MIN_VALUE, FADER_MAX_VALUE,1,254);
    }

    // If outside margin of error of last sent value (reduces jitter)
    if (abs(faderValues[i] - newFaderValue) > FADER_MARGIN) {

      // Update fader value
      faderValues[i] = newFaderValue;

      // Set the flag to handle a fader change
      forceSendMIDI = true;
    }
  }
}

void sendMIDI () {
  // Send either to USB or the MIDI port
  for (int i=0; i<NUM_FADERS; i++) {
    MIDI.sendControlChange(faderCCs[i], faderValues[i], faderChannels[i]);
  }
}

void checkSourceChange () {
  // Check source switch (HIGH=1=true --> should use USB)
  shouldUseUSB = digitalRead(SOURCE_SW);
  if (shouldUseUSB != usingUSB) {

    // Update source
    usingUSB = shouldUseUSB;
    if (usingUSB) {
      USBMIDI_CREATE_DEFAULT_INSTANCE();
    } else {
      MIDI_CREATE_DEFAULT_INSTANCE();
    }

    // Send MIDI to new source
    forceSendMIDI = true;
  }
}


void setup() {

  // Initialize LCD
  lcd.init();                  
  lcd.backlight();

  // Display splash screen
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("Desktop MIDI");
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("(C) 2020    ");

  // MIDI Handler
  MIDI.begin(MIDI_CHANNEL_OMNI);
  checkSourceChange();

  // Initialize Fader inputs
  for (uint8_t i=0; i<NUM_FADERS; i++) {
    pinMode(faderSignal[i],INPUT);
  }

  // Initialize switches
  pinMode(ENCODER_SW,INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(SOURCE_SW,INPUT_PULLUP);

  // Get CC and channel values from memory
  readMemory();

  // Show memory registers for a moment
  if (false) {
    delay(1000);
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print("Memory: ");
    lcd.print((memoryIndex/MEMORY_REGISTER_SIZE));
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.print("Writes: ");
    lcd.print(memoryWrites);
    delay(5000);
  }

  // Show splash screen for at least 1 second
  delay(1000);
  lcd.clear();
  updateFlag = true;
}

void loop() {
  checkRotaryEncoder();
  //checkFaders();
  //checkSourceChange();
  if (forceSendMIDI) {
    sendMIDI();
  }
  checkDisplay();
  // MIDI Controllers should discard incoming MIDI messages.
  // http://forum.pjrc.com/threads/24179-Teensy-3-Ableton-Analog-CC-causes-midi-crash
  while (MIDI.read());
}
```
````

Comment: Please add schematics to see if something is wrong there.

Comment: Your code is far, far, far too complicated.  Cut it down to the most basic test of MIDI *alone*.  Get some debugging logic in the actual MIDI library itself; yes, Arduino makes that hard to do, but that's a cost of using this platform.